# Finite field cyclic subgroup property

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $m\in N$ be a divisor of $q-1$, $q=\vert L\vert$ where $L$ is a field and $H =\{a \in L, a^m=1\}$ show that $\Pi_{a\in H}a=(-1)^{m+1}$

I know that $\vert H\vert=m$

Comment: The elements in $H$ are precisely the roots of $X^m-1$. Now expand $X^m-1=\prod_{a\in H}(X-a)$

Comment: Why does m have to be a divisor of q-1?

Comment: Otherwise 1) the polynomial $X^m-1$ might not be separable or 2) it doesn‘t split into linear factors over L

Comment: As far as I know $X^m-1=\prod_{a\in H}(X-a)
$ implies $-1=\prod_{a\in H}(-a)$ how do I continue?

Comment: $\prod(-a)=\prod(-1)\prod a$.

Comment: Do you get the point, New2?

Comment: Earth to New2Math – come in, please.

Comment: If I have understood correctly since H is a substructure of $L$ one can use the identity $-a=-1 a$ and then the commutativity, by multiplying m times $(-1)$ on both sides of  $-1=\prod_{a\in H}(-a)$ we showed what we wanted to show

Comment: Looks good. So maybe you could write up a solution now, and post it as an answer.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that.